# How do I test this code in RSpec?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Here is the method that called only via ajax in Ruby on Rails 3.2.2

```
def some_ajax_action
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @user_list = User.find_all_by_parent_id(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I wonder is it neccessary (or possible) to test it with RSpec? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
before do
  User.stub(:find_by_id)
  User.stub(:find_all_by_parent)
end

it "finds the user" do
  User.should_receive(:find_by_id).with("37")
  xhr <HTTP VERB>, :some_ajax_action, :id => "37"
end

it "finds the user list" do
  User.should_receive(:find_all_by_parent).with("37")
  xhr <HTTP VERB>, :some_ajax_action, :id => "37"
end
```

Replace `<HTTP VERB>` by whatever is in your `routes.rb` for these ajax calls, e.g. if you have

```
get 'some_ajax_action'
```

then the first one would be `xhr :get, :some_ajax_action, :id => "37"`.