# How to pass in a form param from a Rails controller in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rspec, controller, param

I'm trying to write a spec for one of my Rails 3 controllers. The path I'm trying to hit is:

```
GET /:user_id/photos/shared_photos?page=:page
```

That :page param is usually instantiated through an AJAX request from a JQuery click handler in the browser. However, in RSpec, I'm trying to test the controller directly, and I'm having trouble with the syntax for passing in that :page value. I tried:

```
get :shared_photos, :id => user.id, :page => 2
```

But this doesn't work. I get a routing error, presumably because there is no /:page/ part of the route, so Rails doesn't understand it. My question is, how can I pass that page parameter in from one of my controller specs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding arbitrary parameters to `get` shouldn't cause a routing error (on its own), so I think you're looking in the wrong place for the problem.

If you're testing an AJAX response, perhaps you should try:

```
xhr :get, :shared_photos, :id => user.id, :page => 2
```

Also make sure the format matches whatever your controller expects (if JSON then add `:format => :json`).

See also my earlier answer to this question: [How do I test this code in RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858499/how-do-i-test-this-code-in-rspec/11858852#11858852)